# How to create c++ method with parameters in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I want to create a C++ project which contains a method with some parameters. I want to call this function in C#.

My c++ object should be like this.

```
String DoSomething(String  param1, String  param2)
{
     String Result="";

     //do something

     return Result;
}
```

I know how to use DllImport for c++ methods in c#. However, I cannot find how to pass the parameters to C++ method in C# code and get the result of it.

Comment: Is the C++ project a plain C++ project, or e.g. C++-CLI (managed C++)?

Comment: One can only guess as to what `String` is. Is that your type? Or is it a made up type that is meant to represent some typical string type as yet to be determined?

Comment: I do not know the representative type of C# string in C++. Thats why I made it up. I just want to pass c# string type to C++ written method. Do some calculation with them and return the result back.

Answer (score 1):

If your C++ DLL is all native (no `/CLR`), then you need to `__declspec(dllexport)` the functions (preferably with "C" export). Further, you need to import them in C# code using `DllImport` attribute. This also means, the arguments and return type of function need to be simple (i.e. they cannot be C++ `string`, nor .NET `System.String`).

If this DLL is compiled with `/CLR` switch, life becomes somewhat easier (*perpective!*) - just have a managed class `ref class`. This way you need to add this DLL (which is now a .NET assembly) into **References** of your C#  project.

Comment: I can send parameters like double, int, etc. from c# to c++ methods. However, I want to send a string or string like type to a c++ method.

Comment: You can do that with native function also. For example how to use `CopyFile` : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CopyFile